# Wrap text every 2500 characters in a <div> for pagination using PHP or javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, pagination, word-wrap

I have a long block of text. I'd like to wrap every 2500 characters of this text into a `<div>` such I could do pagination on it.

The following doesn't work:

```
//replace 2500 for 5 for purpose of this example
$text="sfdkjas;fakska;ldjk";
$text=wordwrap($text, 5, '<div class="individualPage">');
```

output:

```
sfdkj<div class="individualPage">as;fa<div class="individualPage">kska;l<div
class="individualPage">djk
```

Obviously I need the closing `</div>` tag to make this work.

Does anyone have a suggestion for this in PHP or Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the `</div>` then?

```
$text = '<div class="individualPage">'
      . wordwrap($text, 5, '</div><div class="individualPage">')
      . '</div>';
```

---

However, you can do even better with javascript: you can [paginate in response to the viewer's screen size](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/WTPzn/).

Just set your HTML to:

```
<div id="target">...</div>
```

Add some css for pages:

```
#target {
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* respect line breaks */
}
.individualPage {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;    
}
```

And then use the following code:

```
var contentBox = $('#target');
//get the text as an array of word-like things
var words = contentBox.text().split(' ');

function paginate() {
    //create a div to build the pages in
    var newPage = $('<div class="individualPage" />');
    contentBox.empty().append(newPage);

    //start off with no page text
    var pageText = null;
    for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        //add the next word to the pageText
        var betterPageText = pageText ? pageText + ' ' + words[i]
                                      : words[i];
        newPage.text(betterPageText);

        //Check if the page is too long
        if(newPage.height() > $(window).height()) {
            //revert the text
            newPage.text(pageText);

            //and insert a copy of the page at the start of the document
            newPage.clone().insertBefore(newPage);

            //start a new page
            pageText = null;
        } else {
            //this longer text still fits
            pageText = betterPageText;             
        }
    }    
}

$(window).resize(paginate).resize();
```

This will work in conjunction with the PHP solution, providing backwards compatibility if javascript is disabled.

Comment: hi @Eric, thanks for this, would you happen to know the javascript solution too?

Comment: @timpeterson: javascript has no built in word-wrapping. Do you care about number of characters, or are you actually after vertical height?

Comment: @Eric, I guess I'm not sure whether I care about characters or vertical height. I guess whatever seems most "natural", meaning whatever would most closely replicate pages in a physical book. Do you have a vertical height solution you could share?

Comment: @timpeterson: [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/WTPzn/) a version that repaginates when you resize the window!

Comment: @Eric, oh cool. I feel bad I wish I could accept both your and -@Peter's answer. If this link is from some other SO answer I'd be happy to upvote that if you'd share that link.

Comment: @timpeterson: I just wrote that now (hence my name in the URL)

Comment: Oh man! responsive pagination, that is bad ass! thanks for this!

Comment: @timpeterson: "responsive" is an innaccurate description of how my browser behaves when I resize it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I'd do it:

```
$out = '';
$text = str_split($text, 2500);
foreach($text as $t){
    $out .= "<div class='individualPage'>".$t."</div>";
}
echo $out;
```

EDIT: This will break apart words, so stick with `wordwrap()`. :D

Comment: This will break words, unlike [`wordwrap`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

Answer (score 1):

Just add an opening div at the beginning, a closing div at the end, and closing divs at the beginning of every iteration.

```
$div = '<div class="individualPage">';
$text = $div . wordwrap($text, 5, "</div>$div") . '</div>';
```

In Javascript, there's not as good of a built in solution.

```
var s = text, div = "<div class='individualPage'>";
while(text.length > 5) {
  s = text.slice(0, 5) + "</div>" + div;
  text = text.slice(5);
}
s = div + s + "</div>";
```

Comment: hi @Peter, thanks for this, would you happen to know the javascript solution too?

Comment: @Eric I'm not sure I see why the answer you linked to would have better performance than this one; they look almost identical, really.

Comment: @PeterOlson: I made that comment before your edit - our answers used to be identical, but I posted first.

Comment: @PeterOlson, awesome thanks! it looks like your Javascript solution would cut words so if both are available your PHP solution seems superior, yes/no?

Comment: @timpeterson: If you want to paginate based on wordwrapping and characters, go with PHP. If you want to paginate on a fixed height, you can do much better with javascript

Comment: @PeterOlson, how would the fixed height change your javascript solution?

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun - here's a fairly ugly JavaScript RegExp that will paginate text and try to not break words.  I'm not sure how well it would perform on a huge amount of text though.

```
var text = ....
// Grab 2500 (or slightly more if it doesn't exactly end on a word boundary)
// characters, or less than 2500 if it's at the end of the string.
text = text.replace(/(((.|\n){2500,2520}?\b)|((.|\n){1,2499}(?!.)))/mg, 
                    '<div class="individual-page">$1</div>')
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLGS3/)

Comment: Nice! You can replace the `(?!.)` with `$`, I think.

Comment: Fails for words longer than 20 characters

Comment: No - it's a multiline regexp - `$` matches end of line.  JavaScript doesn't have the `\Z` that some other languages do

Comment: This simpler regex appears to work for me: `/(.|\n){1,2500}(\b|$)/mg`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Eric: Nice, that simpler regex does seem to work (though it sometimes creates sections somewhat less than 2500 chars)