# Reflow multiple rows and columns with css

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I am trying to create a newspaper-like look through pure CSS where everything flows through columns and onto new pages when it needs more space.

I have tried `flexbox` and `grid`, but it does not work the way I need it to. The content inside can be images, divs, etc. I found it best to illustrate what I am looking to achieve through a picture:

[image: Columns and Rows]

I also created a code pen to try and demonstrate my current attempt:
https://codepen.io/knickfocks/pen/qBZBLqq

As you can see from the above sample code, the items align in columns left to right. The items are assigned various heights just to demonstrate that I wouldn't always know the height, and the content of these items can vary in size. But I am looking to have it move onto the next column row after it runs out of width space. Sorta like how a newspaper reads.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE]

Comment: Hi knickfocks, you might be surprize, but plain CSS 'columns' may be all you actually need: `.parent-container { column-count: 4; column-width: ..... }` where you need to take care that `column-width` fits the viewport size you are targeting. CSS takes care of the `column-gap` by default. `.parent-container>* { break-inside: avoid }` will make sure that the content of child elements is not split over more columns (no widowed or orphaned content).

Comment: Thanks @RenevanderLende I wasn't able to get that into more than one column. Also don't think approach more them onto separate pages?

Comment: Hi knickfocks, I think it is about time you posted a [reprex] we can work with. Default CSS 'columns' read from left-to-right and top-to-bottom and depending on your code we'll have to see where to go with multiple pages...

Comment: @RenevanderLende thanks for your perseverance. I have edited the post to include a code sample. I tired to make it as simple as possible to make it easier to follow.

Comment: I remember coming across question [SO62499782](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62505915/2015909) a few weeks back. Let me know if this works for you.